# I'm trying to figure out how to run a docker container with a django project

Tags: python, django, docker

I've been trying to make a docker container with a django project and have tried different solutions I've found but none of them work. [My current Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF2Rn.png)

So far I've tried different youtube tutorials for setting up python and django docker containers but none of them have worked ending me up with different errors.

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least the following problems with your `Dockerfile`:

- if you use `/app` as `WORKDIR` but copy files into the parent directory
- you can run python instead of python3 since you use python 3 as your base image

So the file could look like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN set -ex \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt \
    && # your other commands ...

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I also recommend creating a user in the container instead of using the root user. And of course `runserver` should not be used in production.

Comment: I attempted to run this in my dockerfile with my other commands and ended up with this

Comment: ype 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    optimizemigration
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush

Comment: sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sass_processor]
    compilescss

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver

Comment: Try `CMD ["python", "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]`

Comment: When I try that CMD I end up with 
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Comment: That sounds that Django is running in your container now. Consider accepting this answer and ask a new question why your db server is not available (provide all needed details).